# Call parameterised constructor after base class after some calculation

Tags: c++, inheritance, constructor

I want to be able to call a parameterised constructor of the base class AFTER I've done some calculation with the input parameters from the derived class constructor.

To what I believe, when you call a constructor of a derived class, the default constructor of the base class is called...

(unless its parameterised constructor is called specifically as so:)

```
DerivedClass(int a,int b) : BaseClass(a,b) {}
```

Is there anyway of doing something like:

```
DerivedClass(int a,int b) { 
   a += 2; 
   b += 5; 
   BaseClass(a, b); // <- this line I am questioning :(
}
```

And I assume what is above doesn't work because the default constructor of the `BaseClass` is already been called..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, you cannot defer calling a base constructor in a derived constructor. The only way to call a constructor is via the constructor initialization list, which is executed before the body of your constructor. If otherwise, you'd see probably lots of nightmarish code, where the base part of an object is not yet constructed but the derived part is trying already to initialize itself...

In your case, you can just do

```
DerivedClass(int a,int b) : BaseClass(a + 2, b + 2) {}
```

PS: You have an error in your code, when you call the `BaseClass` you shouldn't use `BaseClass(int a, int b)`, but only `BaseClass(a, b)`, as it is a function call and not a declaration.

Comment: Ah yes, I presumed so. In my specific case, I have different input parameters for the 2 classes and the only difference between the two constructors is that I have to do some calculation/manipulation to convert the parameters of `DerivedClass` in order to get to the equivalent parameters of `BaseClass`. It seems to make sense to call the `BaseClass` constructor after this calc as its just repeated code otherwise

Comment: @DotSlashSlash factor the common code in another function, and call that one in your constructors. See e.g. Zan Lynx proposal.

Comment: @DotSlashSlash If you just want to increment `a` and `b`, you can simply call your `BaseClass` constructor with incremented values, see the updated edit.

Comment: hmm thanks for the suggestions! Annoyingly, the parameters are of different type and the calculations are quite lengthly and I have quite a lot of different derived classes that all do different calculations, which would require many unnecessary functions that are used once. Maybe i could use lambda functions?! But for my project I think its a bit of an overkill and will leave it the way it is. Thanks for the info though!

Answer (score 1):

You cannot defer the base constructor but you *can* use functions.

For example:

```
DerivedClass(int a, int b) : BaseClass(adjust_a(a), adjust_b(b)) {}
```